# How to upload mp3 file from record_mp3 package for api in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-recording

I'm using this package [record_mp3](https://pub.dev/packages/record_mp3/versions/2.1.0) for recording and play the record with this package [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers/versions/0.15.0) , now I want to upload to api , but I can't get the record file just I have the path only

This is my code for recording

```
RecordMp3.instance.start(
        recordFilePath,
        (type) {
          statusText = "Record error--->$type";
          setState(() {});
        },
      );
```

This is my code for playing record

```
void play() {
    if (recordFilePath != null && File(recordFilePath).existsSync()) {
      audioPlayer.play(recordFilePath, isLocal: true);
      setState(
        () {
          isPlayed = true;
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

So can anyone help me in my case !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the actual content of the file, you can use

```
Uint8List fileContent = await File(recordFilePath )
          .readAsBytes();
```

Comment: I can't understand , kindly can you clear more how i will use it